# What's the purpose of: "using namespace"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-design, using-directives

There are convincing  arguments [against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/) `using namespace std`, so why was it introduced into the language at all? Doesn't `using namespace` defeat the purpose of namespaces? Why would I ever want to write `using namespace`? Is there any problem I am not aware of that is solved elegantly by `using namespace`, maybe in the lines of the `using std::swap` idiom or something like that?

Comment: Less typing is a pretty seductive argument...

Comment: The concept of using 'using' is working around or against the namespace, but it's there when you need it.

Comment: See also Herb Sutter's ["Migrating to Namespaces."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm)

Comment: @James: I kind of disagree with that article :) Existing code did never break due to the introduction of namespaces into the language, because the naming conventions for header files were changed at the same time. So if your legacy codes does `#include <iostream.h>`, then `cin` and `cout` work perfectly fine without the `std::` qualification. So migrating code is definitely not an argument for me.

Comment: @Fred:  So, ignore the short-term solutions.  The correct long-term solution of "avoid using directives entirely, especially in header files" and "never write namespace using declarations in header files" is excellent advice.

Comment: (The ADL-supporting `using std::swap;` trick is described in [this answer to "What requires me to declare using namespace std?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218140/what-requires-me-to-declare-using-namespace-std/2220641#2220641)  (Is this question substantially different from that question?  I don't know if it's an _exact_ duplicate, but they seem to cover the same ground.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For one thing, this is the way to use operator overloads in a namespace (e.g `using namespace std::rel_ops;` or `using namespace boost::assign;`)

Brevity is also a strong argument. Would you really enjoy typing and reading `std::placeholders::_1` instead of `_1`? Also, when you write code in functional style, you'll be using a myriad of objects in `std` and `boost` namespace.

Another important usage (although normally one doesn't import whole namespaces) is to enable argument-dependent look-up:

```
template <class T>
void smart_swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

If swap is overloaded for some type of T in the same namespace as T, this will use that overload. If you explicitly called `std::swap` instead, that overload would not be considered. For other types this falls back to `std::swap`.

BTW, a using declaration/directive does not defeat the purpose of namespaces, since you can always fully qualify the name in case of ambiguity.

Comment: Personally I am fine with "using <X>" its the "using namespace <X>" that I have problems with (with a few exceptions like rel_ops).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times it is just a shortcut for writing code. You can import names into your enclosing context. I usually restrict it to `.cpp` files, because when you include an using directive into a `.h` file, it pollutes all the files in which it is included. Another good practice is restricting the `using namespace` to the most enclosing environment possible, for instance, inside of a method body declaration. I see it as a convenience, no more, and similar to namespace aliasing, such as:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
```

and then you can write

```
po::variables_map ...
```

Answer (score 1):

People specifically object to `using namespace std;` but not to `using namespace BigCorp`; or to referring to `std::cout` (which is using the namespace, just not `using` it, if you know what I mean.) Also, most of the objections to `using namespace std` are in a header file. In a source file, where the effects can be immediately seen, it's less harmful.

Namespaces are an incredibly useful concept that allow me to have a class called Date even though a library I'm using has a class called Date. Before they were added to the language, we had to have things like `GCDate` and `GCString` (my company, Gregory Consulting, predates `std::string`). Making use of namespaces (with or without the `using` keyword) lets us all write cleaner, neater code. But when you have to say `Gregcons::string` every time, you kind of lose the cleaner, neater part. *[Disclaimer: I don't actually use my own string class anymore - imagine some appropriate name conflict.]* That's the appeal of the `using` statement. Keep it out of headers, don't apply it to `std`, and you should generally stay out of trouble.

Comment: I'd say, don't use `using namespace foo`, but `using foo::whatever`; that applies both for standard and other names. For example there's nothing wrong with `using std::cout` if not done in a header.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why `using namespace` was introduced was backwards compatibility: If you have lots of pre-namespace code using lots of (pre-standard versions of) standard library functions and classes, you want a simple way to make that code work with a standard conforming compiler.

BTW, the argument dependent lookup rules at least for C++98 mean that `using namespace std::rel_ops` will *not* do what you want in templates (I don't know if this changed in a later version of the standard).

Example:

```
template<typename T> bool bar(T t)
{
  return t > T();
}

namespace foo
{
  class X {};
  bool operator<(X, X);
}

using namespace std::rel_ops;

int main()
{
  X x;
  bar(x); // won't work: X does not have operator>
}
```

Note that putting the `using namespace` in `namespace foo` won't help either.

However, using *declarations* in the right spot help:

```
template<typename T> bool bar(T t)
{
  return t > T();
}

namespace foo
{
  class X {};
  bool operator<(X, X);
  using std::rel_ops::operator>;
}

int main()
{
  X x;
  bar(x); // now works: operator> found per ADL via the using declaration in `namespace foo`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful when working with libraries with deeply nested namespaces. The Boost library is one such example. Imaging typing `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m` all over the place ...

The thing to avoid is doing `using namespace` in a header file as this has the potential for royally screwing up any program that includes said header. Always place `using namespace` statements in .cpp/.cxx files, so that it's restricted to file scope.

Comment: but a namespace alias could solve this just as well. Or you could just selectively import `matrix` only.

Comment: Or you could use a typedef, e.g. `typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> DoubleMatrix` and use `DoubleMatrix` in the rest of your code. That's the beauty/curse of C++: there are several approaches to solving the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

"Namespaces allow to group entities like classes, objects and functions under a name. This way the global scope can be divided in "sub-scopes", each one with its own name. Where identifier is any valid identifier and entities is the set of classes, objects and functions that are included within the namespace"

More information here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/