# What does this nested namespace definition do?

Tags: c++

I don't even know how to search for that but I tried to test it, still could not understand it. What is the code below means:

```
boost::asio::io_service::id service::id;
```

Got it from: [MaidSafe-CRUX at GitHub](https://github.com/maidsafe-archive/MaidSafe-CRUX/blob/240acca2dd8dd106140a6e8e5e12d457c53ad641/src/service.cpp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is namespace used for, in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333568/what-is-namespace-used-for-in-c)

Comment: Not a bad question, but needs a better title to halt the downvotes, though I can't think of one. Perhaps _What does this nested namespace definition do?_

Comment: @acraig5075 Maybe works better. I will change the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator. The name on the left-hand side denotes a scope; it can be either a namespace name or a class name. The name on the right-hand side denotes a member of that scope.

In your case, there seems to be a class `maidsafe::crux::detail::service`, which contains a static member `id` of type `boost::asio::io_service::id`. In many cases, static members need an out-of-class definition, which is being provided by the code you've posted.

It can be parsed as any other C++ declaration: it declares something named `service::id` of type `boost::asio::io_service::id`. Let's look at the individual components.

Type:

- `boost` is a namespace (in global scope)
- `asio` is a namespace inside `boost`
- `io_service` is either a namespace or class inside `boost::asio`
- `id` is a type inside `boost::asio::io_service`

Name:

- `service` is a class name (probably inside namespace `maidsafe::crux::detail`)
- `id` is a static member inside `maidsafe::crux::detail::service`.

---

*Addendum*

While it does not appear in this question, there's a related syntax you may sometimes encounter in more modern C++ code:

```
namespace maidsafe::rux::detail
{

boost::asio::io_service::id service::id;

}
```

This has been introduced in C++17 as a short-hand for opening multiple namespaces on one line. It's exactly equivalent to the code in the question.

Comment: `service` *might* be a namespace, and can exist in any of `::`, `::maidsafe`, `::maidsafe::run` or `::maidsafe::run::detail`. You are *probably* right about it however

Comment: @Caleth Indeed. Or it could be a class in any of the namespaces you mention. But I feel it's quite improbable, and this issue's level doesn't suggest a need for super-precise, unlikely, potentially distracting details.

Comment: @Angew Agreed with your reasoning, otherwise, I was going to throw some references to qualified-name and qualified-id here.