# can clang-format sort "using namespace <...> " alphabetically?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Say, I have a bunch of .cc source files with statements like

```
using namespace lib::a;
using namespace lib::d;
using namespace lib::c;
using namespace lib::b;
```

I want them to be sorted

```
using namespace lib::a;
using namespace lib::b;
using namespace lib::c;
using namespace lib::d;
```

using a .clang-format file.

Is there a key value pair to achieve this? I know that this works for header files, but I have not seen it for sorting namespaces.

Comment: I am sure you have a good reason to do so, but I would say that using entire namespaces is not a good practice, or at least you have to be very careful about, i.e. not putting many of these in bulk.

Comment: I actually thought it is common practice to use namespaces in source files, but not in header files?

Comment: It is less of a problem in source files, but still quite bad IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For current (latest) clang-format version the answer is: **Unfortunately, No.**
Although it has great "include" sorting features, there is no key for "using"s.

If the feature is added, it will be mentioned in the [Clang-format Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

And also I don't recommend using "using namespace". As it is dangerous and is considered as bad practice.
See the warnings:

1. [Topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. [Topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551409/dangers-of-using-namespace-in-c)

Comment: Sorting `using` declarations is not easy/good practice. Just consider dependent names; clearly inner namspace should not precede its nesting namespace. But if you are using unqualified names( the whole point of `using mamespace`), what is the formatter supposed to do? Should it preprocess the code to check the possibility of reordering, or just reorder and let compilation fail after the change?

Comment: Some namespace are intended to be "used" that way: those which bring `operator`s (`std::litterals` for example).